# Print scalar values

Tags: pyomo

Does anybody know why scalar type parameter values are not printable? I have the following code:

```
dtab = {
('seattle', 'new-york') : 2.5,
('seattle', 'chicago')  : 1.7,
('seattle', 'topeka')   : 1.8,
('san-diego','new-york'): 2.5,
('san-diego','chicago') : 1.8,
('san-diego','topeka')  : 1.4,
}

model.d = Param(model.i, model.j, initialize=dtab, doc='Distance in thousands of miles')

model.f = Param(initialize=90, doc='Freight in dollars per case per thousand miles')

print model.d.values()
print model.f.values()
```

When i run it i get the following results:

```
[1.4, 1.8, 2.5, 2.5, 1.8, 1.7]
[<pyomo.core.base.param.SimpleParam object at 0x000000000B018438>]
```

Can anybody help i realy need to be able to print scalars for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a memory optimization that happens for immutable indexed Params. You would see the same behavior as the singleton case if `mutable=True` was used to initialize the indexed Param. The suggested way of accessing the value of any Param is to use the `value` function provided by Pyomo. E.g.,

```
print([value(v) for v in model.d.values()])
print([value(v) for v in model.f.values()])
```